# Lightweight OS to run virtual machines on?

Tags: boot, virtual-machine, virtualization

It's always complex to install multiple OSs on a machine, but it's easy to use VirtualBox (or similar). But running VirtualBox on a full OS and then running different OSs from there seems a little heavy and unnecessary sometimes.

Is there any simple OS for which the only task is to be a host to easily run and manage virtual OSs on? Something that's not too advanced?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there are no requirements other than virtualization, a so-called "bare-metal" hypervisor is a possible solution. They come with the minimal suite of software required to access network and storage and provide a basic console interface. The actual configuration and management is done remotely with a client or web interface.

The most widely known bare-metal hypervisors are:

- VMware ESXi
- Citrix XenServer
- The Xen Open Source Project (upon which XenServer is built)

They are all free, but offer varying hardware support. The most important thing to note is that Software RAID *will not* be supported, ever. This includes motherboards' FakeRAID.

I've had the best performance using ESXi, on a regular machine.

**Update**
I forgot Hyper-V Server, naturally. It's also free (and probably supports software RAID), but I've had absolutely no luck getting the remote management tools to work. If you don't have Active Directory, I definitely advise you not to use Hyper-V Server. I also think Hyper-V is terrible in general, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: There is also (the free) Hyper-V server as well. However it is ill-suited for desktop virtualization as it doesn't offer hardware passthrough.

Comment: Right you are. Answer updated. Still, everything I mentioned isn't for desktop virtualization (as in virtualization on desktop/workstation machines).

Comment: Is this software meant for servers only? Or could this be installed in my PC?

Comment: There's nothing special about "servers". They're basically just PCs with extended support. They're sometimes also required when you need support (as in support contract with the vendor) for installed software.

Comment: Ok I thought servers sometimes had different processors but I guess not :)